# Permutation in C - Port of java code

Tags: java, c, permutation, porting

I have the following java code for printing out all the permutations of a string. I am trying to convert it to C code. However since C does not support native strings, i am having some difficulties in implementation.

The java code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;

class permute{

static void permuteString(String begin, String end){

        if(end.length() <= 1){
                System.out.println(begin+end);
        }
        else{
                for(int i=0; i<end.length(); i++){
                        String remainString = end.substring(0,i) + end.substring(i+1);
                        permuteString(begin + end.charAt(i), remainString);

                }
        }
}

public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = br.readLine();
    permuteString("",s);
}

}
```

My (incomplete) attempt to port this into C is as follows:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void permute(char* arr, int beginstart, int beginend, int endstart, int endend){

        if(endend-endstart <= 1){
                int i=0;
                for(i=beginstart; i<=beginend; i++){
                        printf("%c",arr[i]);
                }

                for(i=beginend; i<=endend; i++){
                        printf("%c",arr[i]);
                }
        }

        else{
                int i=0;
                for(i=0; i<=(endend-endstart); i++){
                    //HAVING ISSUES IN THIS PART 
                }
        }

}

int main(){

    char arr[3]={'a','b','c'};         
    permute(arr, 0,0,0,3);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not clear on the best way to port the loop with the recursive call. There is dynamic string concatenation which is used in the recursion. I am not sure how to represent it in terms of indexes. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My Java is rusty, but isn't this `String remainString = end.substring(0,i) + end.substring(i+1);` the same as this `String remainString = end;`?

Comment: @alk: No, since Java uses half-open intervals. So `end.charAt(i)` is left out. This makes sense, since exactly this character is added at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't actually learning C with this example, using code that others have written is simpler. Googling for `c permute string` showed up a very nice algorithm, doing the whole permutation in-place, so you don't have to do any memory allocation.

See http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/